# Showing dropdown list when I clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function({$("#more").click(function()$(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow")});});
</script>
```

This is my script for more option. I want to show the dropdown list when I clicked and hide it when I clicked again. Whit this code, all I can get is hiding when I clicked and showing when I clicked again. I want to make it reverse.

How can I change the default display?

Comment: To me it looks like you've got some syntax errors in that. Normally when you're using the function keyword, you'll want to use ```()``` and ```{}``` after it like ```function(…){…}```. This is not the case in at least two places in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, it just has some typo's.

And to define the default state, change the `display` property of `.dropdown` to `none`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#more").click( function() {
        $(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="more">click for more</div>
<div class="dropdown">Droppie down</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS `display:none` property to hide the div on page load.

eg:

```
#more{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#more" ).on('click', function() {
  $( ".dropdown" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
});
```